# Text not being displayed correctly due to code formatted wrong maybe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I have NSMutableDictionary that I'm retrieving text from. I"m trying to display this text into a tableview cell along with some other text that I want added with it. Here's my non-working code:

```
[[cell name] setText:(@"Name:%@",[NameDict valueForKey:@"name"])];
```

I've even tried stringWithFormat and still can't get it to work. I can't get the Name: part to display into the cell along with NameDict value for that key. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: When you run this code given any warning or error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting `[cell name]` from, but this would be a better solution for you based on your code:

```
[[cell name] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@",[NameDict objectForKey:@"name"]]];
```

If you are trying to place that text as the cell text, use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@",[NameDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

Comment: I've already tried your 1st piece of code before coming here for help and I get the following error message "Expected ']'before ';' token.

Comment: [cell name] is a label that I have for a custom cell.

Comment: The reason you got the error on the first one was because you left out a ], copy / paste MY first example.

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code and still receive that error about the ']'

Comment: oops, seems I left out a bracket, try again.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this whole time I was missing that bracket. I thought that I counted them all but I guess not. Ok, its' working now. Thanks for the help Wrights!! I think it's time for me to goto bed now. lol Thanks again.

Comment: Well, your original issue wasnt the bracket. Your whole statement wasnt correct.

Comment: Well, true but even before that I tried the exact same code as yours, I'm not even joking with you lol and I kept getting that error so I just scrapped it and started working with the code that I posted on here because it wasn't giving me any errors. I even tried adding that bracket and I guess it added a bracket to the left automatically and I didn't catch it, oh well... I'm just glad it's fixed. Sometimes I look right at the issue and won't see it until someone else helps. I appreciate your help. Thanks.